# Taharas mishpacha class for men

Tags: halacha, marriage, adult-learning, men-male, niddah

Many women take kallah classes before getting married in order to be familiar and comfortable with the laws of taharas mishpacha. I have heard that there are similar classes for men, and it makes sense to me that the man should be comfortable with the laws as well. When I search online for information about such classes, though, I find very little information. What exactly would be covered in a chasan class, and how might one find such a class in his region?

Comment: Indeed, as [msh210's answer explains](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18708/5), any rabbi of an Orthodox synagogue or Yeshivah should be able to direct you to classes. According to your Mi.Yodeya user profile you live about a 10 minute drive from one of the largest Orthodox communities in the United States, so it should not be too difficult to find a teacher.

Comment: @SethJ This is true. There is certainly no shortage of Orthodox Jews where I'm from :)

Comment: partial dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2134/759

Comment: @Daniel Congrats for escaping your nerdity! You do realize that according to Pirkei Avot, you're not supposed to degrade yourself? I guess it takes an ex-nerd to grasp that concept ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, such classes exist, and are recommended for potential bridegrooms. Speak to the rabbi of any orthodox synagogue, and he should be able to direct you someone who can tutor you in this field. So, I suspect, can the head or *mashgiach* of any *bes midrash*. Covered topics are *hilchos nida* and *v'sasos*, *k'vod ishto*, and others, though the exact list varies from tutor to tutor.

Comment: Hi msh210. Can you translate the terms in your last sentence? I was linked to this from a recent question I asked regarding what topics are covered in this class.

Answer (score 4):

These classes are usually one-on-one chevrutot with your rabbi (or someone he directs you to), so you're not going to find them online, or even with a fixed schedule.

Talk to your rabbi and he will direct you what to do.