# What are Chattan or Kallah classes?

Tags: marriage, wedding, adult-learning, chassan-groom

I guess I'm becoming more "outdated" regarding the current "frum fad".

A shadchan as well as a few young boys and girls told me that at some point between engagement and marriage they must attend a Chattan (for groom) or Kallah (for bride) class.

I have no idea what these classes are about. When I think of "class" I think of something in a school where they get homework and / or have labs.

What is the purpose of these classes? Are they mandatory? What type of person teaches these classes - a rabbi or "lay" person? What subjects are taught? Is this something given in a university, JCC, Adult Ed or privately? How long do these classes typically last and how frequently per week are they usually given? How many students typically attend? Can these be taken online?

I apologize for my ignorance and asking so many questions, but, this really puzzles me to the point that I'm not completely sure what to ask about it. My wife and I have been married a long time and we never took any of these classes. Did we miss out on some important opportunity, and should we be taking one of these classes, now, perhaps?

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18707/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2134/759

Comment: I recommend striking the last paragraph. It looks like it's asking for personal advice.

Comment: @DoubleAA partial dupe. Perhaps, an answer can include a link to that question. I'm more curious as to what these classes are for.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I've deleted one paragraph, but left in the last one, for now. Being completely ignorant on this topic, I'm asking in general if a married couple should take this type of class. I can rephrase the paragraph, if you think that helps.

Comment: The classes are essentially basic sex ed, laws of mikvah and niddah, and some tips on personal relationships.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Was this from a class that you took, or this is common to all classes? If the latter, you may want to post as an answer.

Comment: "What exactly would be covered in a chasan class" asks the first link that DoubleAA linked? How is this not a dupe of that?

Comment: The main reason for those classes is Hilchas Niddah (at least that's what I've heard). It's one of those things that are both fairly complicated and you can't just "see" what others are doing.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is certainly a dupe, unless the OP is insisting on a detailed summary. Which is certainly not appropriate.

Comment: These classes ought to be taught to men by a practicing rabbi. Apart from hilchos niddah they also have to be taught about the  "biah".  It is a difficult subject to discuss with a stranger and therefore the chasan should have first discussed it with his rabbi (who then wont be a stranger) in case he has problems and shaalot.

Comment: @heshy "a detailed summary" is an oxymoron, you realize :-) See my comment ^^. It gives you an idea what I'm seeking.

Comment: @DoubleAA When you cite a question, could you use its words instead of a hyperlink? That would be very handy instead of opening it and reading the question and coming back.

Comment: @alberko the names of all linked questions are in the right column of the page

Comment: Not linked, but citing question in comments. Compare yours #1 vs mevaqesh above. The question instead of a hyperlink.

Answer (score 4):

In Israel these classes are mandatory to get married. They are delivered in multiple places by different groups, e.g., the official rabbanut organizes some, private orgs as well (e.g., Aish HaTorah) and more insulated communities will have theirs. They are typically taught by women (often rabbanits or women in charge of mikvaot) for women. Some include a tour of a mikve to get familiar with it.

Content of the classes typically include the laws of mikve and nidda and some thoughts on making relations in the couple bloom. In more traditional communities, I understand they include content on physical relations as well.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4-WNZG3mpE&feature=youtu.be) for a view on a modern version of these classes by Aish Hatorah targeted at secular people in Tel Aviv.

PS. Sources for the above are discussions with the rav who runs Aish Tel Aviv as well as a Bnei Brak rav specialised in mikva and nidda.